# Facebook iOS update : integrated the conversions APIs with native php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-pixel

I am using PHP with Laravel to create an E-commerce and integrating Facebook pixel and everything was working properly,
then after IOS 14 update, the pixel integration isn't working properly, so I heard that if we integrated the Facebook conversion APIs and add the domain verification code it would solve the problem

so I tried to add this

```
<meta name="facebook-domain-verification" content="myCode" />
```

so my question is: is it correct that integration conversion APIs would solve the problem,
and if it is correct - I don't know where and how to integrate these conversion APIs

Comment: HI I've just added the conversion API into my project can help, do you still need it ?

Comment: yes please i do

Comment: I'd provide the sample code and you can use the same just pass your credentials and pass the data from the ajax

Answer (score 4):

The *Facebook Conversion API events* are more powerful than the *Facebook Web Pixels*. The Conversion API event gets fired through backend logic. you can use the ajax call from the front end, and check the event triggers on the Facebook panel

**Facebook Pixel Conversion API**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/

you can generate the access token from https://business.facebook.com/event_manager select your site and generate the Facebook pixel

javascript ajax function and you can simply call this ajax function where you want to trigger pixel

**Function Call**

```
let event_id = d.getTime(); 
fbq_custom("PageView", window.location.href, {event_id: 'PageView-'+event_id}, {event_id: 'PageView-'+event_id}) }
```

*Function Definition*

```
function fbq_custom(trace = 'PageView', source_url = '', data = {}){

    data.trace = trace;
    data.source_url = source_url
    $.ajax({
        url: "/conversionAPI/",
        data: data, 
        type: "post",  
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("server event test");
        }
     });
}
```

I just use this package

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk

**PHP API**

```
use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\Content;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\CustomData;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\DeliveryCategory;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\Event;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\EventRequest;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\Gender;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\UserData;

$trace = $_POST['trace'];
$source_url = $_POST['source_url'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'] ? $_POST['firstname']: "";
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'] ? $_POST['lastname']: "";
$phone =  $_POST['telephone'] ? $_POST['telephone']: "";
$email =  $_POST['email'] ? $_POST['email']: "";
$event_id =  $_POST['event_id'] ? $_POST['event_id']: "";
$action_source =  $_POST['action_source'] ? $_POST['action_source']: "website";


$access_token = 'here you need to add the access token';
$pixel_id = 'your pixel id';

if (is_null($access_token) || is_null($pixel_id)) {
    throw new Exception(
        'You must set your access token and pixel id before executing'
    );
}


Api::init(null, null, $access_token);
$api = Api::instance();
$api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());
$events = array();

$user_data = (new UserData())
    ->setClientIpAddress($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
    ->setClientUserAgent($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
    ->setEmail($email)
    ->setPhone($phone)
    ->setFirstName($firstname)
    ->setLastName($lastname);


$custom_data = (new CustomData());

$event = (new Event())
    ->setEventName($trace)
    ->setEventTime(time())
    ->setEventId($event_id)
    ->setEventSourceUrl($source_url)
    ->setActionSource($action_source)
    ->setUserData($user_data)
    ->setCustomData($custom_data);

$events = array();
array_push($events, $event);


$request = (new EventRequest($pixel_id))
    ->setEvents($events);
$response = $request->execute();



print_r(array(
    "status" => 200,
    "message" => "pixel code added successfully",
    "source_url" => $source_url,
    'trace' => $trace,
    'event_id' => $event_id,
    "response" => $response,
    "user_data" => $user_data,
    "event" => $event

)) ;
```

Comment: First time, someone posted clear code to set up the conversion API. I am getting error on inputs that trace , lastname, telephone are undefined index. Can you please guide me? 

Comment: undefined where on the Facebook panel or on the code ?

Comment: in the code. From where are you getting these inputs?

Comment: I have a form where user input their information and I did submitted according to the user information.

Comment: obviously you have to pass the input values otherwise it consider it undefined.

Comment: What I am trying is to record visitor information on ViewPage content and then trigger an event on facebook pixel. So, I don't want to have a form and i want direclty to get information from visitor's browser.

Comment: i think the problem with your code while you are extracting information from browser